# Filter objects that exist in the Foreign Key relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have the following relationship in my data:

**Models:**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    concepts = models.ManyToManyField(Concept, related_name='course_concepts')

class Concept(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

But I would like to build a query set of Concepts that belong to a particular course (*course_x*).

I have tried the following but continuously get reference errors:

```
Concept.objects.filter(self__in=course_x)
```

As such, what is the correct way to query only objects that match a foreign key relationship for a particular object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you might filter for `Concept` objects that pertain to a `Course` with a particular `name`:

```
concepts = Concept.objects.filter(course__name="Your course name")
```

Or, you could filter for concepts that relate to a queryset of courses:

```
concepts = Concept.objects.filter(course__name__icontains="mathematics")
```